# removing Percentage symbol

Tags: shell, scripting

trying to remove percentage symbol '%' from this shell script

```
df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Percentage: %s \n", $5}'
```

output:

```
Percentage: 2%
```

want to make the output like this

```
Percentage: 2
```

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the interpretation of the value in `$5` as a numeric value.  This can be done by adding zero to the value before printing it using the `%s` format:

```bash
df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { printf "Percentage: %s\n", 0+$5 }'
```

Or, by using `%d` to format the value as a decimal integer rather than as a string:

```bash
df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { printf "Percentage: %d\n", $5 }'
```

Or, explicitly delete the last character from the string before printing:

```bash
df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { printf "Percentage: %s\n", substr($5,1,length($5)-1) }'
```

```bash
df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { sub(".$","",$5); printf "Percentage: %s\n", $5 }'
```

Or, simply remove all `%` characters in the input:

```bash
df -h | tr -d % | awk '$NF == "/" { printf "Percentage: %s\n", $5 }'
```

```bash
df -h | awk '{ gsub("%","") } $NF == "/" { printf "Percentage: %s\n", $5 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

And one more way to remove the `%` symbol:

```
df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { printf "Percentage: %s\n", int($5) }'
```

Comment: didn't know i can use casting Thanks!

Comment: @AliEbadi It is not casting (in the sense of c language(, it is a simple `awk` function.